# Atom folder Icon

Tags: atom-editor

I am seeing this icon on my atom text editor for the first time. Can anyone tell me what it means? I am referring to the `dist` folder.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This icon is used for a [Git *submodule*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), which means that the folder is a separate Git clone (fixed to a certain commit) of a different repo.

Check whether you have a file called `.gitmodules` in your project's root folder, it should show you which repo that folder points to.

That would also explain why that folder was not pushed to Git. Git is simply keeping track of which repo and commit this folder points to. When cloning this repo on another server, you'll have to make sure that the submodule is checked out as well.

Please take a look at the documentation for Git submodules that I linked to in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what it does, but that folder was not pushed to git correctly when deployed. Something about it being ignored although it was not on my .gitignore.